# Hanging square and deflection tactic leading to a back rank checkmate

Tags: strategy, tactics

```
[FEN "2r1r1k1/5ppp/8/8/Q7/8/5PPP/4R1K1 w - - 0 1"]
```

The important square of e8 square is hanging. It is hanging because if white can take that square it's checkmate. Is this a hanging square tactic?

If the rook on Rook on c8 is deflected from the  protection of e8, is it called a deflection tactic?

```
[FEN "6k1/3qb1pp/4p3/ppp1P3/8/2PP1Q2/PP4PP/5RK1 w - - 0 1"]
```

Here, the important f8 square is not hanging, so white plays Qf7+ to deflect the king from protection of f8 square, thus leading to checkmate.

Comment: I've added the FEN tag so we can easily see the position you are talking about. There is no deflection. White to move plays RxR and QxR in any order and it is checkmate. Where do you think the deflection occurs? Or did you enter the wrong position, maybe miss out one or more pieces?

Comment: There is a mate in 1 threat on e8 square, but the rook on c8 defends it. So if it can be deflected mate is achieved. Rxc8+ move deflects the black rook from the defense of e8, because when Rxc8 is played by black, black rook no longer defends that square thus leading to checkmate. @BrianTowers

Comment: Or maybe it's a hanging square tactic, where the important e8 square is hanging, So white takes that square to deliver checkmate

Comment: I have never heard of a "hanging square" tactic. Hanging piece, yes, weak or undefended square, yes, but never hanging square. Can you give a link to something that explains what you mean?

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: Not sure why people are voting to close this. I can see two quite clear questions. The answer to the second is "no", "coercion" is about the closest I can come up with you must have a name for every move on the chess board. I can't answer the first because I don't know what the poster means by a "hanging square"

Comment: 34 years as a Master...I have never heard the term "hanging square".

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard of the term "hanging square" before. But you're right that the c8-rook would be deflected (or "attracted") if it were taken away from defending the rook on e8.